# Why is the same card being drawn in this while loop for card deck?

Tags: python, oop

I have built a deck of cards in the following code. I'm running a while loop to try drawing cards from the deck, but the same card is repeatedly drawn for the entire length of the deck. Obviously, what I want is to draw a *different* card each time.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))
        return self.value


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
                #print("{} of {}". format(v, s))

    def show(self):
        for cards in self.cards:
            print(cards.show())

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, Deck):
        self.hand.append(Deck.draw_card())
        return self

    def show_hand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()
            return card.value


Computer = Player("Computer")
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
while len(deck.cards) > 0:
    Computer.draw(deck)
    Computer.show_hand()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `show_hand` has a loop that exits immediately upon its first iteration, so it just prints the *first* card and then exits... no matter how many cards are in the hand. So there is no problem with *drawing* the cards. The problem is in the *printing*...

Since `card.show()` *prints* something, `show_hand` really shouldn't return anything, and you should just let the loop make all its iterations.

So I would suggest changing it to this:

```
    def show_hand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()
```

And then call it only once, like this:

```
while len(deck.cards) > 0:
    Computer.draw(deck)
Computer.show_hand()
```

### Some improvements

I would avoid methods that call `print`. Because of the principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), this really should not be done in a class, but left to the main driver code.

Also, it would be nice if the player's hand was also an instance of `Deck`. That way you could apply the power of that class also to the player's hand.

Finally, make use of `__repr__` methods to control how instances of your classes are represented in string format.

For example:

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def fill(self):
        self.cards = []
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.add(Card(s, v))
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return ", ".join(repr(card) for card in self.cards)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        return self


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = Deck()

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.add(deck.draw())
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} has {}".format(self.name, self.hand)


Computer = Player("Computer")
deck = Deck().fill().shuffle()
k = 3
for _ in range(k):
    Computer.draw(deck)
print("After drawing {} cards:\n{}".format(k, Computer))
```

### Making it a game

Here the latter idea is used to run a game of "lower/higher":

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def fill(self):
        self.cards = []
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.add(Card(s, v))
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return ", ".join(repr(card) for card in self.cards)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add(self, card):
        return self.cards.append(card)


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = Deck()

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.add(deck.draw())
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} has {}".format(self.name, self.hand)

def play():
    deck = Deck().fill().shuffle()
    computer = Player("Computer")
    computer.draw(deck)
    print(str(computer))
    while deck.size() > 0:
        guess = "?"
        while guess not in "hl":
            guess = str(input("Will the next card be higher or lower than {} (h or l)?\n".format(computer.hand.cards[-1]))).lower()
        computer.draw(deck)
        print(str(computer))
        diff = computer.hand.cards[-1].value - computer.hand.cards[-2].value
        if diff <= 0 and guess == "h" or diff >= 0 and guess == "l":
            print("Ah... wrong guess! Game over.")
            return
        print("That was well guessed!")

    print("Unbelievable: you guesses were right for the whole deck!")

play()
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, but what if the `show_hand()` is meant to be used again and again? once I take it off the while loop, I can't write other lines for another player to draw cards and show its hand, can I? I'm still new to python; thanks for your suggestions and patience.

Comment: I don't really understand what problem you see with calling it multiple times.

Comment: Added a section to my answer with a way this can be used as a game.

Comment: let me put it this way. If I were to add another player to draw and show card from the deck instead of just the computer, but I take `computer.show_hand()` off the while loop, then computer will draw all the cards in the deck, leaving nothing for other player to draw, right?

Comment: That would be the case if you let the computer draw *all* cards in one go. Of course, you shouldn't do that. Make it loop where in the body of the loop first the computer draws a card, and then the player draws a card. Put please... if *that* is your question, then update your question and describe the desired input/output sequence.