# Deck of card not completely returned, parts of play() not executed (Python)

Tags: python, oop

I have built a simple "Higher or Lower" card game for two players using reference from [Why is the same card being drawn in this while loop for card deck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554721/why-is-the-same-card-being-drawn-in-this-while-loop-for-card-deck). The game flow should be like this:

1. First player (Computer) to draw a card from the deck and show it
2. Each player place a guess whether the next card drawn will be higher or lower in value to the first card drawn
3. The second player (Player_1) draw a card and show it
4. Whoever guess is correct will get one point
5. After the last card of the deck is drawn, the points are to be tallied

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.cards = []
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
            return self
                #print("{} of {}". format(v, s))

    def show(self):
        for cards in self.cards:
            print(cards.show())

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self

    def draw_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add(self, card):
        return self.cards.append(card)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.cards)


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = Deck()

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.add(deck.draw_card())
        return self

    def show_hand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()


def play():
    Player_1 = Player("Player 1")
    Computer = Player("Computer")
    Higher_or_lower = ["h", "l"]
    player_1_score = 0
    computer_score = 0
    deck = Deck().build().shuffle()
    Computer.draw(deck)
    Computer.show_hand()

    while deck.size() > 0:
        answer = "?"
        while answer not in "hl":
            Player_guess = str(input("What is your guess: higher or lower (h or l)?\n".format(Player_1.hand.cards[-1]))).lower()
            Computer_guess = random.choice(Higher_or_lower)
            print("You guess " + str(Player_guess))
            print("The computer guess " + str(Computer_guess))
        Player_1.draw(deck)
        Player_1.show_hand()
        diff = Computer.hand.cards[-1].value-Player_1.hand.cards[-1].value
        if diff <= 0 and answer == "h" or diff >= 0 and answer == "l":
            if Player_guess == answer:
                player_1_score += 1
                print("You guessed correctly")
            elif Computer_guess == answer:
                computer_score += 1
                print("Your guess is incorrect")
    else:
        if player_1_score > computer_score:
            print("You are the winner! You scored " + str(player_1_score - computer_score) + "higher")
        elif player_1_score == computer_score:
            print("You have a draw game")
        elif player_1_score < computer_score:
            print("You have lost. You scored " + str(computer_score - player_1_score) + "lower")


play()
```

There are a few problems in this code. First, the deck was not iterable. But this has been resolved by editing `show_hand(self)`.

Second, the deck has only one suit (Spades)

Third, codes after `print("The computer guess " + str(Computer_guess))` is not being executed.

Comment: This code has many problems. Moreover, I don't understand the game you want to implement. Can you edit your question and add an explanation in detail of how the game is supposed to work, with an example?

Comment: @trincot edited my question for more details

Comment: OK, but I fail to say what the relevance is of two players drawing cards. It would be the same if each card was just drawn without anybody owning that card, and the players just guessing. I don't see the relevance of the players accumulating cards in their hands. It seems unnecessary and meaningless. Oh, and I see you have accepted an answer... so I will move on then ,-)

Comment: @trincot I get your point that one player makes more efficient code. But as a learner, I do want to explore different ways of writing code, and even if the result may not be the best, I do get to learn something. If I simply take yours (for one player), then I don't get to create my own code.

Comment: You have an unconditional `return` statement inside a `for` loop, in `Deck.build`.  The loop is therefore pointless, as only the first iteration (the one generating Spades) ever takes place.

Comment: *"I get your point that one player makes more efficient code"*: no that is not my point. My comment has nothing to do with efficiency of code. It is about the "game" itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.hand` is the `Deck` object, in `for card in self.hand` you are trying to iterate over it. You want to iterate over its `cards` property

```
def show_hand(self):
    for card in self.hand.cards:
        card.show()
```

Comment: the error is no more using your solution, but `Player_1.draw(deck)` and `Player_1.show_hand()` isn't running. Also, the deck seems to have just one suit. Can help?